# react-select not updating value when changing option

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I load my supplier using SWR.  But it is wrapped in various classes.  I get it like so:

`const supplier = new Supplier(supplierID)`

This gives me a supplier object.

I then have a select drop down:

```
options = assetPriceCategories.map((category) => {
            return {
                value: category.node.id,
                label: category.node.name,
                property: 'assetPriceCategory'
            }
        })
        selected = { value: supplier.assetPriceCategory.id, label: supplier.assetPriceCategory.name }
<Select name="assetPriceCategory"
                    instanceId={useId()}
                    value={selected}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={option => supplierDataChange(option)}
            />
```

This works, the select shows and the options show, and the selected item is selected. My onChange:

```
const supplierDataChange = (object) => {
        if(typeof supplier[object.property] === 'object') {
            supplier[object.property].id = object.value
        } else {
            supplier[object.property] = object.value
        }
    }
```

Doing console.log() at the end of this function proves that the supplier has changed, but the `<Select>` object does not update, it remains the same option as loaded in the beginning.

Comment: Are you updating the value of "selected"?

Comment: @Aadmaa `selected` is created from `supplier.assetPriceCategory` which is passed into the component

Comment: @Aadmaa I have updated the code to display this

Comment: Is the supplier variable getting reset on each refresh? Consider making the supplier and "selected" variables local React.useState(), and consider utilizing React.useMemo () to set up those options so they don't get recreated on each refresh.

Comment: @Aadmaa the supplier variable is loaded from SWR from an API.  So whenever the API is updated, the variable is updated.  If I update the database the <Select> value changes, however If I change the value from the onChange event, it does not.

Comment: We can fix this; need a little more info. Can you show (1) the whole functional component and how it is called; and (2) a version of the Supplier class (you can scale it down to the minimum properties)? I think you are probably just resetting the value on each refresh of this component, but we can probably refactor the component a bit too.